# Protecting Network attached storage

Tags: security, backup, storage

In your answers, please keep in mind that it is all about a home network.

What is the best way of protecting a network attached storage from the outside world?

Currently i have a NAS connected behind my internet gateway. On the first day of use i found "copy.exe" within one of the disks attached to the NAS.

What should i do in order making it as secure as possible?

Comment: Just because it is about a home network, does that automatically make it not sysadmin related? I do plenty of sysadmin at home, and many small businesses use "home network" hardware and software.

Comment: This shouldn't have been closed since sysadmin covers even the smallest network, down to the individual computer level.

Comment: I've got to agree with the other comments here.  This could just as easily be a remote office or a home office that's being managed by a corporate sysadmin.  Closing it as 'not sysadmin related' is not appropriate, IMO.

Comment: I also agree this is sysadmin related. I don't think this question should be closed.

Comment: It's lot easier to "protect" something on your home network where the only users are yourself and your family than in an office where you're dealing with all sorts of people with various levels of trustiness.

Comment: Well it looks like some of us were born with keyboard instead of hands. I first posted the same question on stackoverflow.com. and was kindly advised to post the question to this website. And so i did. I guess i 'll have to wait for HomeNetWorkForDummiesWithSillyQuestions.com to get an answer. Thank you Kara.

Comment: It seems Kara has let moderator abilities go to her head.  This is one of quite a few closed questions I've noticed that I don't agree should have been closed.

Comment: Too bad they don't have real feedback on this site.

Comment: 3 votes is plenty to reopen.

Comment: When there are six users on the site capable of voting on closes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most NAS provides some sort of built in security restrictions allowing you to limit what hosts can talk to it.  Some even allow you to configure users/passwords.  Anything that the vendor provides for locking it down, do it.

Additionally, make sure it is located on your network in such a way that it cannot be seen or accessed from the outside world.  If you're not using some sort of router/firewall/etc that prevents inbound access, you should be.

If you want absolute best security for it you can get, pick up a cheap second switch and an extra network card.  Put the second network card(s) in the box(es) that needs to access the NAS.  Configure it with an IP address on a different network from your normal LAN.  Run the NAS on the separate "storage only" network that isn't even directly connected to the internet-accessible network.

Basically, you have two LAN's.  One is for normal network purposes, accessing the Internet, etc.  The other one is just used by the NAS and devices that need to connect to it, all running on separate network hardware (network cards).  By placing the NAS on a dedicated network like this, someone has to first compromise one of your computers before they can even begin to attempt to access the NAS.

[Edited to add additional clarification of a dedicated storage network.]

Comment: Could you please provide me a link related to separated "storage only" network?

Comment: @gipap: You're kidding, right?  Read the answer: "a cheap second switch and an extra network card" -- a physically separate LAN, in other words.